# Handle C++ templates in Qt5

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, qt

Searching for a solution to my problem I've read many posts regarding templates in **Qt** (including those on SE) and didn't find a complete solution (or I should say a complete example of a solution) so this post. It is not only to review the code but I think it could be useful for others with similar needs.

## Motivation

I have a library that provides config `struct`s for different modules like this :

```
struct UConfig<V2718> // V2718 is a class representing the V895 module
{
    // V2718 specific parameters
};
```

In the library I also have two functions:

```
template <typename M_TYPE>
WriteConfigToFile( const UConfig<M_TYPE>& cfg, /*...*/ )

template <typename M_TYPE>
ReadConfigFromFile( UConfig<M_TYPE>& cfg, /*...*/ )
```

which serialize/deserialize config-`struct` and write/read it to/from a file.

And I am developing a GUI for these modules with **Qt**. For every such module there is a window widget that  provides interface to the module. The thing is *those windows have something in common : for example, every such window have a menu that allows a user to save/load configuration to/from a file*. And from the above we conclude that the procedure should be the same regardless the module (window). The scheme is the following (writing):

[image]

Of course, the `CreateConfig()` function is module-specific, but the scheme is kind of polymorphic. And this is true for everything that involves `UConfig<M_TYPE>`. So the obvious solution would be for every concrete window to inherit from a class template:

```
template <typename M_TYPE>
class ModuleWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    virtual UConfig<M_TYPE> CreateConfig() = 0;
};

class V2718Window : public ModuleWindow<V2718>
{
    Q_OBJECT

    UConfig<V2718> CreateConfig() override;
};
```

Oops! **Qt**'s Meta Object Compiler doesn't support class templates.

## Solution

The solution I'm suggesting is to mix the `QVariant` and template member functions, and the fact that although you cannot have template slots you can connect the template *instance* to a signal.

## Code

The presented code is a Minimal Reproducible Example.

### config.h

This file simulates a library : something that you cannot (or don't want to) change and what you want to work with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename M_TYPE>
struct Config;

template<>
struct Config<int> { int a; }; // <--- config for the Int window

template<>
struct Config<double> { double a; }; // <--- config for the Double window

template <typename M_TYPE>
void WriteConfigToFile( const Config<M_TYPE>& cfg ) // Doesn't actually write anything to a file
{
    std::cout << "The a field of " << typeid( cfg ).name() << "is " << cfg.a << "\n";
}
```

### test.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVariant>

#include "config.h"

/* This is necessary to represent our configs as QVariant */
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Config<int>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Config<double>)


class QPushButton;

class Base : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected :
        QPushButton* fButton;

        virtual QVariant CreateConfig() = 0; // <--- builds the config from widgets' data and puts it in QVariant

        template <typename M_TYPE>
        void SaveConfig() // <--- The procedure to save config : implemented once and for all
        {
            Config<M_TYPE> cfg = qvariant_cast<Config<M_TYPE>>( this->CreateConfig() );
            WriteConfigToFile( cfg );
        }

    public :
        Base( QWidget* parent = nullptr );
        virtual ~Base();
};


class Int : public Base
{
    protected :
        QVariant CreateConfig() override;

    public :
        Int( QWidget* parent = nullptr );
        virtual ~Int();
};

class Double : public Base
{
    protected :
        QVariant CreateConfig() override;

    public :
        Double( QWidget* parent = nullptr );
        virtual ~Double();
};
```

### test.cpp

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

#include "test.h"

Base::Base( QWidget* parent ) :
    QWidget( parent )
{
    /* Create the window skeleton : the button to save config
     * BUT not connect its click to anything - it will be done
     * in the concrete module class */
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    fButton = new QPushButton( "Write config to file" );
    layout->addWidget( fButton );
    setLayout( layout );
}

Base::~Base() { };


Int::Int( QWidget* parent ) :
    Base( parent )
{
    connect( fButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Base::SaveConfig<int> ); // <--- this window knows the M_TYPE so connect
}

Int::~Int() { }

QVariant Int::CreateConfig()
{
    Config<int> cfg;
    cfg.a = 6;
    QVariant qv;
    qv.setValue( cfg );
    return qv;
}

Double::Double( QWidget* parent ) :
    Base( parent )
{
    connect( fButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Base::SaveConfig<double> );
}

Double::~Double() { }

QVariant Double::CreateConfig()
{
    Config<double> cfg;
    cfg.a = 28.0;
    QVariant qv;
    qv.setValue( cfg );
    return qv;
}
```

The `main` function is trivial. To run :

```
qmake -project "QT += widgets"
qmake
make
```

Comment: "The presented code is a MRE." The only meaning of MRE that I know is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meal,_Ready-to-Eat .  I don't find any code-related meanings for such an acronym.  Is it a Qt thing?

Comment: Just a thought:  Does Copperspice work any better?  _"All functionality originally provided by `moc` was replaced with compile time templates"_ ... _"A template class can now inherit from `QObject` with no restrictions on data types"_

Comment: @JDługosz, haha :) Sorry I thought the acronym is very popular on SE. Edited.

Comment: @JDługosz, (on Copperspice), thank you for a recommendation. I will consider this library in the future, but I see it requires the C++17 standard which is unavailable for now on our relatively old machines.

Comment: you know, a new compiler can be installed... it doesn't matter how old the machine is.

Comment: @JDługosz, I tried that once. And it was a nightmare to maintain the system. Most likely, I have not enough experience and knowledge but it's not an option for now.

Comment: @LPDPRDX the compiler should be installed in a different directory, not replace the "system" compiler.  For example, mine (on an AWS server) is `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/gcc` and the ancient past-end-of-life compiler is _still_ at `/usr/bin/gcc`, undisturbed.

Answer (score 2):

Not Qt related but...

See [Core Guidelines C.128](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override).

`virtual ~Int();`
should be:
`~Int() override =default;`

Your definitions of empty destructors (e.g.)

```
Double::~Double() { }
```

are de-optimizations in two ways.  First, they are non-inline and not in the header, so (unless you have working whole-program link-time code generation) the pointless function call will be made every time.  Second, the compiler "understands" the generated destructor better and and further optimize.  So, use `=default` whenever you need to explicitly specify that, and don't write an empty destructor.